# What's the next character in a list (job interview qa)

Tags: arrays, character

got this list in online job interview:

```
["b", "c", "e", "g", "k", "m", "q", "s"]
```

and I was supposed to figure out the next letter. (...)

Comment: So did you get the job?

Comment: Never mind - the answer is that the letter positions in the alphabet correspond to prime numbers, and the next one is "w"

Comment: implosible!?@# thank's anyway.

Comment: I don't like such questions as all possible answers are correct since one has no information whatsoever about what is "correct".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming, although the OP didn't necessarily realise that at the time.

Comment: letter no 23.. in alphabets

Comment: Stackoverflow.com : logic puzzles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why such questions are asked in interviews; not sure what is the point of this, but here is the answer (in Python):

```
>>> import string
>>> [string.ascii_letters[i-1] for i in (2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23)]
['b', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'k', 'm', 'q', 's', 'w']
```

Answer (score 0):

Yey Friend Your next word is 'W'
beacuse your all words number is prime ...
b=2,
c=3,
e=5,
g=7,
k=11,
m=13,
q=17,
s=19,...
and 
next prime number is 23
and 
w=23